# Design Bug: Alignment of tags is off alignment with the OP in the index page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tags and OP should be aligned and they aren't.

[image: Design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed. Should line up like every site on the network now. I wanted more negative space and to have a dropped down user signature... but things got tightened up and so i guess that can't be lower by 4 px now. good eye.

Comment: It is not fixed on my Safari or Chrome, even after a hard refresh.

Comment: Ok, it's still off, by 1 px, but ok...